# Error while trying to import 'oh-my-posh' with Import-Module in windows terminal

Tags: windows, import-module, oh-my-posh

I installed the oh my posh module and am trying to import it with `Import-Module oh-my-posh`. But I'm getting the following error

```
Downloading oh-my-posh executable for 7.36.1
Get-CimInstance : Invalid class
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\oh-my-posh\7.36.1\oh-my-posh.psm1:66 char:18
+ ...    $arch = (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Processor -Property Architec ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041010,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand

Import-Module : oh-my-posh: Unsupported architecture:
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module oh-my-posh
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (oh-my-posh: Unsupported architecture: :String) [Import-Module], Runti
   meException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : oh-my-posh: Unsupported architecture: ,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Why am I getting this? I ran `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` before

Answer (score 0):

The module is no longer supported, and this issue has been resolved in the meantime because of it. Have a look [here](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/migrating) to get you going again.